# Tunnelerror during Ecmwf api job

Tags: python, api, urllib

I get the following Error after using the MarsAPI from ECMWF to download data.
I use currently Python 2.7 for that:

```
2019-11-28 16:18:18 ECMWF API python library 1.4.0
2019-11-28 16:18:18 ECMWF API at https://api.ecmwf.int/v1
WARNING: URLError received None <urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 503 Service Unavailable>
WARNING: URLError received None <urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 503 Service Unavailable>
WARNING: URLError received None <urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 503 Service Unavailable>
WARNING: URLError received None <urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 503 Service Unavailable>
WARNING: URLError received None <urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 503 Service Unavailable>
WARNING: URLError received None <urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 503 Service Unavailable>
WARNING: URLError received None <urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 503 Service Unavailable>
WARNING: URLError received None <urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 503 Service Unavailable>
WARNING: URLError received None <urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 503 Service Unavailable>
WARNING: URLError received None <urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 503 Service Unavailable>
WARNING: URLError received None <urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 503 Service Unavailable>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/thomaskociok/bin/mars", line 31, in <module>
    c.execute(req, target)
  File "/home/thomaskociok/.conda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ecmwfapi/api.py", line 510, in execute
    c = APIRequest(self.url, "services/%s" % (self.service,), self.email, self.key, self.trace, verbose=self.verbose, quiet=self.quiet)
  File "/home/thomaskociok/.conda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ecmwfapi/api.py", line 365, in __init__
    user = self.connection.call("%s/%s" % (self.url, "who-am-i"))
  File "/home/thomaskociok/.conda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ecmwfapi/api.py", line 133, in wrapped
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/thomaskociok/.conda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ecmwfapi/api.py", line 250, in call
    res = opener.open(req)
  File "/home/thomaskociok/.conda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 429, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/home/thomaskociok/.conda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 447, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/home/thomaskociok/.conda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/home/thomaskociok/.conda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1241, in https_open
    context=self._context)
  File "/home/thomaskociok/.conda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1198, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 503 Service Unavailable>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bin/OpenLE-meteo-ecmwf__ecmwfapi", line 552, in <module>
    MarsCall( marsdict )
  File "./bin/OpenLE-meteo-ecmwf__ecmwfapi", line 348, in MarsCall
    subprocess.check_call( ['mars',marsjb] )
  File "/home/thomaskociok/.conda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 190, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
```

After a few hour google I only found that the Error can be a part of urllib. But how I can fix this?

is it possible to change urllib directly to 2?